# Upgraded to Xcode 7.2 and my UI Tests Pass without running

Tags: xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I just upgraded to Xcode 7.2 and now my tests succeed without even running.  As soon as it finishes building, it gives me the "Test Succeeded" message and the console shows no output.

Is anyone else having this issue?

UPDATE: So it looks like it's not working only on one specific device, which is an iPAD AIR 2, and the UI Test platform doesn't even install onto the device.  It doesn't work on 2 separate machines both with Xcode 7.2.

Comment: My tests don't run and my tests fail with:
*** Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1.

Comment: @dave_gerard I was running on an iPad Air 2 when I was having this issue and it seems to be working fine for me with an Iphone 6 plus.  Have you tried other simulators/devices?

Comment: I closed Xcode and the Simulator and re-opened both and now my tests are running fine. It has happened 2-3 times so far and restarting Xcode + Sim fixes it.

Comment: maybe You have to enable `Enable UI Automation` at `Settings / Developer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved when I updated my device to iOS 9.2.  I don't see why this could've been the issue seeing all my other devices managed to run tests fine on 9.1.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Xcode 7.3.1 and iOS 9.3.1. Rebooting the iOS device solved my problem.